# user_id isn't saving on newsletter model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have 3 models, user.rb, blog.rb, post.rb.

For some reason the user_id is returning nil after a user creates a blog, and the blog isn't actually saving.

**MODELS:**

```
USER.RB -- 
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, 
         :validatable

  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :blogs, through: :subscriptions 

  validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :password, on: :create         

end

BLOG.RB -- 
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :subscriptions
  has_many :posts
  belongs_to :user

  scope :for, ->(user) do
    if user 
      Blog.all
    end
  end

end

POST.RB -- 
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

**CONTROLLERS**

```
BLOGSCONTROLLER -- 
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:my_blogs]
  before_action :set_user
  before_action :set_blog, only: [:show, :update, :edit, :destroy]

  def index
    @blogs.all
  end

  def new
    @blog = @user.blogs.build
  end

  def create
    @blog = @user.blogs.build(blog_params)
    if @blog.save
      redirect_to new_blog_post_path(@blog, @post), notice: "You've successfully created a blog"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def my_blogs
    @blogs = @user.blogs
  end

  def show
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @blog.update(blog_params)
      redirect_to @blog, notice: "Blog succesfully updated."
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @blog.destroy

    redirect_to blogs_path, notice: "Your blog has been deleted."
  end

  private

  def set_user
    @user = current_user
  end

  def set_blog
    @blog = @user.blogs.find(params[:id])
  end

  def blog_params
    params.require(:blog).permit(:name, :user_id)
  end

end

POSTSCONTROLLER -- 
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :update, :destroy, :edit]
  before_action :set_blog

  def create
    @post = @blog.posts.build(posts_params)
   # @post.blog.user = current_user
    if @post.save

      redirect_to blog_post_path(@blog, @post), notice: "Post successfully published."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Post could not be published."
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def new
    @post = @blog.posts.build
  end

  def show
  end

  def update
    if @post.update(posts_params)
      redirect_to [@blog, @post], notice: "Post successfully updated."
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Post has not been updated."
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy

    flash[:notice] = "Post was deleted."
    redirect_to @blog
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @post = @blog.posts.find(params[:id])
  end

  def set_blog
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    flash[:alert] = "The blog you were looking " + 
                    "for could not be found."
    redirect_to root_path                    
  end

  def posts_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :blog_id)
  end

end
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I make it so that, when users visit the my_blogs page they will see all of the blogs that they've created? Of course, the newsletter must first be associated with the blog..I have a user_id column on the newsletter table.

Please advice!

Comment: You're redirecting to a post after creating a blog. You have no `@post` in your create method within your blogs controller.

Comment: Thanks Jon, after a user creates a blog, they should be re-directed to posts/new to create a new post. What @post method should be in the blogs controller create action? The issue is that the user_id isn't being saved when a blog is creatd. So when I search current_user.blogs.each do |blog| blog.name it returns empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Change the line `has_many :blogs, through: :subscriptions` in **User** to something like `has_many :subscribed_blogs, through: :subscriptions, class_name: "Blog"` and add the line `has_many :blogs` and it should work.

### Long answer

Your problem is that you have two similarly-named associations between `User` and `Blog`: a blog `belongs_to :user` and `has_many :users, through: :subscriptions`. You probably don't want to do this!

In the other direction, your User model only defines one association: `has_many :blogs, through: :subscriptions`. When you call `@user.blogs.build(blog_params)`, **this** is the association that gets used - it will create a new Blog *and* a new Subscription, and the foreign keys will be saved in `Subscription#user_id` and `Subscription#blog_id`. `Blog#user_id` gets ignored as it's irrelevant to this kind of association.

```
What you think you have:
  User.id = 15
  Blog.user_id = 15

What you actually have:
  User.id = 15
  Subscription: user_id = 15 & blog_id = 9
  Blog.id = 9
```

To get the former type of association (the one that actually uses `Blog#user_id`) you want to add the line `has_many :blogs` to User model - no `through`. Unfortunately this won't work, as the existing `has_many... through` association is also called `blogs`, and you can't have two associations with the same name. So rename the old association to something like `subscribed_blogs` or `blog_subscriptions` and you should be fine.

Comment: You are a true gentleman, and scholar! Thank you this worked :)

Comment: Ah one last issue, when i type newsletter.user it shows the user that created the newsletter, but when I type @user.newsletters it returns a empty array? We're so close!!

Comment: I can't see any reference to a "Newsletter" in the code you've posted... can you post your `Newsletter` model?

Comment: Ah sorry, I mean @user.blogs, it returns an empty array but blog.user returns the user record?

Comment: Have you saved the blog yet? If you load up a fresh user from the database then `user.blogs` won't return anything unless the blogs have also been saved to the database.